# Calculating reset in Excel Sheet

Tags: ms-office

Please put the **following formula** in **C2 cell** and then copy to below cells.

The **following formula** might be good at beginning.

```
=IF(SUM($B$2:B2)>50,"total value equals or less than 50","")
```

Comment: So it's not related to colours - when does the summing reset?  Does it restart on row 7 because adding 18 to 45 would take it over the 50 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied a helper column D with formula

in cell D2:   `=IF(C2="less than",SUM(B$1:B2)-SUM(D$1:D1),0)`

in cell C2:   `=IF(SUM(B$1:B3)>50+SUM(D$1:D1),"less than","")`

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yes it corresponds to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula in `C2` (see the illustration below):

```
=IF(SUM(B$2:B3)-SUM(B$1:INDEX(B$1:B1,MATCH("ZZZ",C$1:C1)))>50,"Break",0)
```

and the following number format in column `C` (to suppress zeros):

```
;;;@
```

[image: Breaks]

There is an error in your example in rows 13/14.
(I have shortened the text.)

Comment: This should be a "last" word in alphabetical order. In other languages you can use other words.

Comment: It is difficult to find the reason if I can't see your sheet. What results do you get? Without formatting you should get `0` in column `C` in cells which seem to be empty.

Comment: I was reminded by this post that `INDEX` can return a reference. :)

Comment: @DannyColeiro which function is volatile in this formula?

Comment: If this volatility is a problem you should use a helper column.